# How do I mute output when a text is not recognized?

Tags: flex-lexer

When a text is not recognized by the scanner, by default, is sent to `stdout`. How to avoid this?
I could add many rules like

```
ANY (?s:.)
// ....
<TOKEN1>{ANY} {}
<TOKEN2>{ANY} {}
<TOKEN3>{ANY} {}
```

But I believe there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

At the very end of your flex input file's rules section (just before the second %%), add the following rule:

```
.    /* suppress unrecognized characters */
```

It is important this is the last rule.  It matches ANY single character and will then perform nothing with it because the only code supplied for an action is a comment.  As long as it is the last rule, it will not be matched unless no rule above it matches that next character, in isolation, as the longest possible regular expression match.  So if you have a rule above for the equal operator, for example...

```
=    { code_here_to_work_with_equals(); }

.    /* suppress unrecognized characters */
```

...the lexer will find both rules match the character '=', and it will pick the rule earlier in the file to break the tie.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Dot cannot recognize '\n', so it's not what I need. A better construct is my regex "ANY" that I wrote in my question. Anyway if you use many TOKENS (I don't know the correct name of them) you have to repeat the rule for each token or separate them with a comma, which is not maintanable.

Comment: Yes.  It's true '.' doesn't match a newline... after more than a decade of using flex, I take for granted newlines are almost always (I can't think of a time I've seen otherwise) consumed by some other rules, specifically whitespace rules or EOL rules (for generating EOL tokens in line centric grammars like assembly or for bookkeeping of line numbers for error reporting.  Otherwise, the `.` rule is extremely common, but if newlines are not consumed in other rules, `[.\n]` is just as good and easier to read than `(?s:.)` since that rule interprets `.` uniquely.

Comment: BTW, when you are using `<TOKEN>{ANY}`in your post, are you intending to mean TOKEN as a flex conditional activating rule for {ANY} or just as a place holder to mean some token followed by any character?  I'll admit I took it as the later, but either way that has little to do with not printing out unexpected characters.  

Can you provide some example input and identify the tokens you want to match and which characters wouldn't (the ones you want not to print to stdout)?  Does your application encourage its input to have unrecognized characters?... e.g., characters after `;` are ignored?

Comment: Yes, with <TOKEN> I mean a conditionally activated rule, I couldn't find the right words. The problem is this: I always use flex to deal with files which contain many portions of useless text which must be discarded. Because I use to debug with printf I'd like to flush useless text instead of make confusion while debugging. I'll provide you an example as soon as I find some time, thanks for the answer.